# Python using urllib2 to scape images?

Tags: python, screen-scraping, jpeg

I'm scraping http://apod.nasa.gov/ for its image of the day.  So far, I have been able to return what I believe to be the image source tag.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from urllib2 import urlopen
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

class Apod:
    def apod_wallpaper(self):
        self.soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen('http://apod.nasa.gov/').read())
        self.pic = self.soup.find('img')
        return self.pic


print Apod().apod_wallpaper()


>>> ./apod.py

>>> <img src="image/1208/Ma2011-2Tezel900.jpg" name="imagename1" alt="See Explanation.
Moving the cursor over the image will bring up an annotated version.
Clicking on the image will bring up the highest resolution version
available." />
```

I'm not sure how to download the actually **.jpg** from here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Step 1: read the HTML file.

Step 2: Extract the `src` attribute from the image you found.  Concatenate the domain `http://apod.nasa.gov/` with the `src` value `image/1208/Ma2011-2Tezel900.jpg` to come up with a URL to use to get the image.

Step 3: Run `urlopen(...).read()` on it, and write it to a file

---

For example:

```
data = urlopen('http://apod.nasa.gov/image/1208/Ma2011-2Tezel900.jpg').read()
open('mypic.jpg', 'wb').write(data)
```

Comment: Well, talk about over thinking it, :|  Thanks for the help, gahooa

Answer (score 3):

You want [`urlparse.urljoin()`](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urljoin).

```
>>> urlparse.urljoin('http://apod.nasa.gov/', 'image/1208/Ma2011-2Tezel900.jpg')
'http://apod.nasa.gov/image/1208/Ma2011-2Tezel900.jpg'
```

Comment: Like my comment above, definitely over thought this one.  I had just started to scrape and was thinking there was a specific method for it.  Cool that you showed an instance of urlparse in action :D thanks